# Excel VBA script for loop with dates

Tags: vba, date

I am calculating the number of work hours (8am to 8pm) between the 2 given dates, excluding Weekends and Public holidays, but my code syntax is incorrect.

**Sample data:**

Start day: 17/06/2011 08:00:00 AM

End day: 19/06/2011 08:00:00 PM

```
Sub SLA_Days_Resolved_F()
    Dim x As Integer
    ' Set numrows = number of rows of data.
    NumRows = Range("F2", Range("F2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

    Dim total As Integer 'to count the total hours
    Dim st As String 'start date cell
    Dim en As String 'end date cell
    Dim destCell As String
    Dim d As Date ' for the loop

    total = 0

    ' Establish "For" loop to loop "numrows" number of times.
    For x = 2 To NumRows + 1
        st = "G" & CStr(x) 'reference to the cells
        en = "D" & CStr(x)
        'loop from start date to end date
        For d = Date(Range(st)) To Date(Range(en))
            'check if the current date is found is a Public holiday in the range or if a weekend
            If ((Vlookup(d,lookups!$o$3:$p$26,2,false))=1) or (weekend(d))Then
                'minus 8 to remove hours before 8am.
                total = (total + Hour(d) + minutes(d) / 60) - 8
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: @David Zemmens: I am missing this line of code with reference to st and en variables. st = "G" & CStr(x) and en = "D" & CStr(x). I have edited this on the main post.

Comment: Why don't you Dimension `st` and `en` as Range variables, and use `.offset(x,0)` to redefine them within the `For x...` loop. It would save you a lot of extra coding.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are not assigning any values to variables `st` or `en`.

`Date` is not a function available in VBA. You will probably need to use DateSerial function. Here is a simple example of looping over dates which you should be able to modify.

```
Sub LoopDates()
Dim d As Date
'Loop the days beteween today and March 1, 2013.
For d = DateSerial(Year(Now), Month(Now), Day(Now)) To DateSerial(2013, 3, 1)

    Debug.Print d  'Prints the "d" value in the immediate window.
Next

End Sub
```

Also, you can't just put worksheet formulae in VBA.  This line is definitely wrong syntax for Vlookup, and `Weekend` is not a formula that I'm aware of (testing it seems to confirm it is not a valid call on worksheet or in VBA.

`If ((Vlookup(d,lookups!$o$3:$p$26,2,false))=1) or (weekend(d))Then`

Rewrite as:

```
If Application.WorksheetFunction.Vlookup(d,Sheets("lookups").Range("$o$3:$p$26"),2,false)=1 _
    or Not Application.WorksheetFunction.Weekday(d) Then
```

**ANOTHER EXAMPLE** of a date loop where I have dimensioned the variables in what I believe to be a more efficient manner:

```
Sub Test()

Dim st As Range
Dim x As Integer
Dim stDate As Date
Dim enDate As Date
Dim d As Date
Dim numRows as Long

NumRows = Range("F2", Range("F2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

For x = 0 To NumRows-2
'SET YOUR VARIABLES HERE
' This may seem redundant or unnecessary for this case, but it makes structuring nested
' loops easier to work with, and then there are fewer places to make changes, 
' if you need to make changes.

    Set st = Range("G2").Offset(x, 0)
    Set en = Range("D2").Offset(x, 0)
    stDate = DateSerial(Year(st), Month(st), Day(st))
    enDate = DateSerial(Year(en), Month(en), Day(en))

    'Then, loop through the dates as necessary
    For d = stDate To enDate
        Debug.Print d
        'Do your code here.
    Next

Next


End Sub
```

Comment: I modified the for loop as suggested.For d = DateSerial(Year(Range(f)), Month(Range(f)), Day(Range(f))) To DateSerial(Year(Range(g)), Month(Range(g)), Day(Range(g))). Throws error on this line.

Comment: I am approaching my problem differently. I am dropping this. Thank you for your suggestions.